# Jmeter Scripts Taking Time Run With 2 CSV Configs

Tags: jmeter

Jmeter Scripts are taking Double the Time when 2 CSV configs are introduced. Can anyone provide solution for same?

Comment: Take a screenshot of the threadgroup and provide more information

Answer (score 1):

it's not possible to "provide solution for same" without seeing:

1. Initial test plan
2. Test plan after adding CSV Data Set Config(s)
3. Results file from both executions
4. Just in case [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging)

Per se CSV Data Set Config won't generate extra requests unless you have a [While Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-while-controller-jmeter/) configured to loop until there are entries in the CSV file.

Also be aware that you can limit JMeter test duration using 2 approaches:

1. "Specify thread lifetime" input at [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) level:

   [image]
2. Use [Runtime Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Runtime_Controller) which controls for how long are its children allowed to run

   [image]

In both aforementioned cases the test won't last longer than 5 minutes

Comment: Thanks for the response. The issue is when there was one csv config the whole suite for the scripts took 1 hour and when 2 configs were introduced it took 2 hours to run. We have ensure that there is no sleep time introduced.